# How to get SQL query results into several tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have basically very simple query:

```
SELECT id, 
       other_data 
FROM Data_Table 
WHERE id IN ( SELECT id 
              FROM Other_Table 
              WHERE other_id = @Selected_id
            )
```

I run this query from C# towards SQL Server. 
I would like to have the results of my query into several datatables instead of one datatable in the resulting dataset.

So, basically the results of the query should be like this:

```
id,   other_data
------------------
2     foo
2     goo
2     hoo

id,   other_data
------------------
3     woo
3     eoo
3     roo

id,   other_data
------------------
5     boo
5     noo
5     moo

etc.
```

What kind of query should I use?

Comment: Try to write multiple `select` queries in a single `stored procedure` and use it in your C#.

Comment: What resulting data set?  You are returning the data to the application and can do whatever you like with the results.

Comment: _" I would like to have the results of my query into several datatables instead"_ Why? If you want to present them separately, just have the frontend do that. It's more efficient for SQL just to return the whole lot and leave presentational details to the frontend.

Comment: Gordon & underscore_d, Thanks. Maybe I need to do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use stored procedure with multiple select statements to achieve it.

Your stored procedure should look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourSPName
    (
     --Write your parameters here if any
     @Selected_id INT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MyIDs TABLE (ID INT, isProcessed BIT)
    DECLARE @CurrentID INT

    --Holds all IDs from your table
    INSERT INTO @MyIDs
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, 0 FROM Other_Table WHERE other_id = @Selected_id

    --Loop until all IDs are processed
    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM @MyIDs WHERE isProcessed = 0)
    BEGIN
        --fetch the topmost unprocessed ID
        SELECT TOP 1 @CurrentID = ID
        FROM @MyIDs
        WHERE isProcessed = 0

        --Your query goes here
        SELECT id, other_data 
        FROM Data_Table
        WHERE id = @CurrentID

        --Set the processed status on the same record
        UPDATE @MyIDs
        SET isProcessed = 1
        WHERE ID = @CurrentID
    END

END
```

And, you should write your code like this:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection("Connection String");
var command = new SqlCommand();

var sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
var dataSet = new DataSet();

command = new SqlCommand("YourSPName", conn);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Selected_id", id); // Your parameters will be added like this, if there are no parameters, remove this line

sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

conn.Close();
```

Now you can use `dataSet.Tables[index]` to refer to any datatable returned from the stored procedure. e.g.

```
dataSet.Tables[0]
dataSet.Tables[1]
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how many SELECTs I need to do, so I woud need some kind of loop which loops through the results of 
( SELECT id 
              FROM Other_Table 
              WHERE other_id = @Selected_id
            )

Comment: @MarkkuRintala I have updated the answer for the same. I assumed you will be passing the `@Selected_id` from your C# code. So, I made it the parameter to the `stored procedure`.